# how can I clear the app invite notification on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

When I use the [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to send notification requests, they arrive as expected. However after the user follows the link and accepts the App permissions, the notification persists.

Is there some additional call I need to make to clear the notification? I know it auto expires after some time, but that doesn't seem entirely satisfying.

Am I missing something, or is this really not doable?

Comment: "_However after the user follows the link and accepts the App permissions, the notification persists._" Meaning there is still 1 on the notifications or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you delete app request when users accept an app invitation.

When user accepts an invitation i.e. comes to your application canvas page by clicking on app request notification,  Facebook sends comma separated ids in "request_ids" parameter. You can get this requests and delete it using graph api like this :

Here I am deleting the last request id :

```
$ids = $_GET['request_ids'];
$id_arr = explode(",",$ids);
$count  = count($id_arr);
$delete_url="https://graph.facebook.com/".$id_arr[$count-1]. "?access_token=" . $token . "&method=delete";
$result = file_get_contents($delete_url);
echo("Requests deleted (true or false) ?" . $result);
```

Note request_ids field may contain multiple request id if he has been invited multiple times. I am not sure but you may need to delete all.