# Get facebook friend user id, without sending for him notification

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

is it possible to do similar thing like "apprequests" (app request dialog), with callback to get user friend id, without sending for him notification? Because everytime user select friend, he sends for him notification, how I can remove such thing(sending notification), or it is impossible?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you asked completely the wrong question. Why don't you describe what you *want*, instead of how something else behaves?

Sounds very much like you want a friend selector - so build one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the user id of a friend without an app request, you have to authorize the user and read his friendlist. Without authorization, there is no other way.

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I can suggest is to send a notification and then immediately delete it. You can check this thread to know how to delete a request: [how can I clear the app invite notification on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116053/how-can-i-clear-the-app-invite-notification-on-facebook/13116250#13116250) . But It doesn't make sense as to why you are using such tricks to get user's friends id.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, not user_id but user friends id. And I can't delete friend notification I think so? or there is a way too?